# How can I output data with special characters visible?

Tags: java, io

I have a text file that was provided to me and no one knows the encoding on it. Looking at it in a text editor, everything looks fine, aligned properly into neat columns.

However, I'm seeing some anomalies when I **read** the data. Even though, visually, the field "Foo" appears in the same columns in the text file (for instance, in columns 15-20), when I try to pull it out using `substring(15,20)` my data varies wildly. Sometimes I'll pull bytes 11-16, sometimes 18-23, sometimes 15-20...there's no consistency between records.

I suspect that there are some special chartacters, invisible to my text editor, but readable by (and counted in the index of) the `String` methods. Is there any way in Java to dump the contents of the file with any special characters visible so I can see what I need to Strings I need replace with regex?

If not in Java, can anyone recommed a tool that may be able to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with having a look at the file directly. Any code adds a layer of doubt. Take a Total Commander (or equivalent on your platform), view the file (F3) and switch to hex mode. You suggest that the special characters behavior is not even consistent between lines, so you should get some visual clue about the format before you even attempt to fix it algorithmically.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do...~see~ what's there before programming around it. Thanks for the Total Commander tip! Looks like that'll help a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing the contents of the file as individual integers or bytes? That way you can see if there are any hidden characters.

Comment: For the field I'm trying to pull, yes...I used `substring` to grab individual bytes (as `char`), and I did not see anything odd. I'd like to try something that bypasses the `String` methods, but I'm not sure where that lives in Java--or if I need another tool entirely.

Comment: Try to print what's before. That will tell you, by example, if there are 8 spaces or 1 tab (`\t`).

Comment: Maybe you could ask for each `char c` if `Character.isLetterDigit(c)` and if it's not then you print it as integer. So you can find the special chars easier.