# Why does Java's `indexOf` return negative numbers other than (-1)

Tags: java, indexof

I have a multi-line text input file: If the String "Log Number:" is present, it is immediately followed by a log number. If the String "Log Number:" is not present, there is no log number in that record. There is ALWAYS the String "Log Date:". It follows "Log Number:" if present and appears at that position in the file if it does not.

My `inputLine` comes out of a `BufferedReader` that's reading my file line-by-line.

```
...
if((inputLine.indexOf("Log Number:"))>-1) {
  logNumRecStart = inputLine.indexOf("Log Number:")+12;}
else
  logNumRecStart = 0;
logNumRecEnd = inputLine.indexOf("Log Date:");
...
logNumber = inputLine.substring(logNumRecStart,logNumRecEnd);
...
```

and when I output the Start and End indeces, here's a sample of what I get.

```
49>>>  -0 to 357
50>>>  -0 to 361
51>>>  -0 to 384
52>>>  -371 to 390
53>>>  -315 to 334
54>>>  -325 to 352
```

Records 49-51 are cases where "Log Number:" does not appear in the input line, and as expected, `logNumRecStart` is set to 0. Records 52 - 54 *do* include "Log Number:", but the index is being set to a negative number, resulting in my substring getting an out-of-bounds exception. Visually inspecting the file demonstrated the presence (or absence) of the test values in the appropriate lines. My `logNumRecEnd` value is correct in ALL cases.

By counting characters in the source file for `inputLine`, I've verified that if the negative value of `logNumRecStart` were POSITIVE, it'd be the correct number.

I'm not using `lastIndexOf` so I have no idea why I'm getting the negative values. Can anyone see something I'm missing or soemthing I need to check that I've not mentioned?

Comment: Can you give us more details, such as the part of the code that prints that output?

Comment: Can you post the actual IndexOutOfBoundException message you get?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: String index out of range: -389

Comment: @AntonioJunior: `System.out.println(recNum+">>> "+logNumRecStart+" to "+logNumRecEnd);` If I add my `logNumber` field to the print, I get the out of bound exception.

Comment: This doesn't explain how you print `-0` Even if indexOf were returning a large negative number, it would go into the else branch `logNumRecStart = 0;`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: exactly...I'm not sure where `-0` comes from either. I'd started the day with `!=-1` as my test and *every* record had an out of bounds exception. Changing to `>-1` allowed me to actually print the values. I think I'm going to have to go back and look at my data again. My substrings were inconsistent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630801/how-can-i-output-data-with-special-characters-visible yesterday afternoon until I replaced some special characters with spaces in a hex editor. Though I got 'em all, but...

Comment: @dwwilson66 See my edit for a suggestion on how to change the code.

Comment: I had the vendor re-run the data extract and specificlaly requested that they only include printable ASCII characters. Everything runs like a dream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((inputLine.indexOf("Log Number:"))>-1) {
  logNumRecStart = inputLine.indexOf("Log Number:")+12;}
else
  logNumRecStart = 0;
logNumRecEnd = inputLine.indexOf("Log Date:");
...
```

This is all correct and is giving you correct values, so your error must be in the ... that you left out somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

I would change the code to the following to make sure you have no errors.

```
final int logNumberPos = inputLine.indexOf("Log Number:");
final int logNumRecStart = logNumberPos > -1) ? logNumberPos + 12 : 0;
final int logNumRecEnd = inputLine.indexOf("Log Date:", logNumRecStart);

if (logNumRecEnd > 0)
    logNumber = inputLine.substring(logNumRecStart, logNumRecEnd);
```

---

> 49>>>  -0 to 357

I suspect you are printing a `-` in front of the number as there is no `-0` for `int` (BTW: you say this is `0`)

> 52>>>  -371 to 390

and this should be `371 to 390` which makes more sense.

BTW: There is such a thing as `-0.0` for `double` and `float`

Comment: So, where's the index out of bounds exception coming from?